# Jquery autocomplete with static remote url and loading indicator

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

So, I had a working autocomplete, only my source was echo of a remote php file. Since this php page takes some time to generate all the data it would just stall my page.

Hence, I want jquery to load the php page instead. This is just a 1 time static load of the data, since it takes some time to load it.

This is what i had:

```
$( "#tipjob" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data,
    select: function(event,ui) {
        window.open(ui.item.url);
        $tipjob.attr("value","");
    }
}).data("catcomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>").data("item.catcomplete", item).append("<a><img src='images/" + item.color + ".png' align=right>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
});
```

And then I had a `var data = [ include php file` ..

So I tried using source: "page.php", etc but that doesn't get loaded at all for me. I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/includes/jsonjobs.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#tipjob').autocomplete({
                source: data
            });
        },
        error: function(result) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

This does load the file, but then the autocomplete fails to work too, besides that if its slow it does not show the "loading" indicator in the autcomplete field. (I am using the `.ui-autocomplete-loading` for that)

Loads of examples show either some form which uses a search php (but I just want static data) and other examples show loading the data then passing it to the autocomplete but then you dont get the "loading" if you start to type (it should only show that if its not fully loaded)

Anyhow, I come to the point that I believe I need to create a function for the source but I just lost it there.

Snippet of the source loaded:

```
[{ "label": "commit-master", "category": "Fishes -  1.504", "color": "blue", "url":     "http://bla.com/commit-master/" },
{ "label": "nightly-master", "category": "Fishes -  1.504", "color": "blue", "url":     "http://bla.com/nightly-master/" },
{ "label": "release", "category": "Food -  1.504", "color": "blue", "url": "http://bla.com/ACTIVERING-release/" },
...];
```

**P.S.:** files are all on the same url/location (so no cross domain stuff)

Update:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#tipjob" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/includes/jsonjobs.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function( data ) {
                    response (data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event,ui) {
            window.open(ui.item.url);
            $tipjob.attr("value","");
        }
    }).data("catcomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>").data("item.catcomplete",  item).append("<a><img src='images/" + item.color + ".png' align=right>" + item.label + " </a>").appendTo(ul);
    });
});
```

> source: jsonjobs.php and above example both don't show up in network calls if I check it out on Chrome browser with F12.

Update 2: Found out an error at the bottom of the generation of the json which did not have the " quotes around a value. After this a direct source: "jsonjobs.php" works. But now it also shows a nice loading indicator. Only problem i face now is that it reads it constantly when i type a letter and does not slim down my selection. (but i am close now)

Update 3: This below loads all my values correctly, and only loads it once. This does remove the whole loading indicator, but its the best i can do. Only now i loose my special markup i had, with images and such and category's. The snippet below this one still does that correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/includes/jsonjobs.php",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#tipjob').autocomplete({
            source: data,
                            select: function(event,ui) {
                                    window.open(ui.item.url);
                                    $tipjob.attr("value","");
                            }
            }).data("catcomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                            return $("<li></li>").data("item.catcomplete", item).append("<a><img src='images/" + item.color + ".png' align=right>" + item.label
    + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
            };
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Sorry, cannot load the jenkins job data for some reason");
    }
});
});
```

^ Good, but no images, but only does 1 call.

```
 $(function() {
            $( "#tipjob" ).catcomplete({
                delay: 0,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/includes/jsonjobs.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                                    response(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                            select: function(event,ui) {
                                    window.open(ui.item.url);
                                    $tipjob.attr("value","");
                            }
            }).data("catcomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                            return $("<li></li>").data("item.catcomplete", item).append("<a><img src='images/" + item.color + ".png' align=right>" + item.label
    + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
            };
    });
```

^ does show correct images and all, but constantly load on entering text and does not slim down the selection when typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $( "#tipjob" ).autocomplete({
   source: "/includes/jsonjobs.php",
 });
```

or

see **[this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)**

```
 $( "#tipjob" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
$.ajax({
url: "includes/jsonjobs.php",//if remote thant full path
dataType: "jsonp",
data: {
name_startsWith: request.term
},
success: function( data ) {
response( $.map( data.d, function( item ) {
return {
label: item.Category,
value: item.Category//or your field
}
}));
}
});
}
});
```

Comment: As stated above, just added source: jsonjobs.php does not seem to work. I've update the first post with above try:

Answer (score 0):

If your static list does not depend on `IDs` (as in `key-value` pair generally used in HTML `<option>` tags) and you are working with `HTML5`, you may try with the [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) tag too.

> This would not require you to implement an autocomplete yourself. The browser would do this for you. And this is compatible with almost all of the modern browsers.

You may check out some [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/html/datalist.html) too. You may check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) too.

Comment: I dont know what part your pointing too, the data i have is json and is valid. That is not a problem, or are you suggesting something else?

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting you to create a `<datalist>` with your data. You load static data on the page (no AJAX) and it automatically works as an `autocomplete` textbox. Did you go through the examples?

Comment: Would a datalist not change the way i use my data? I use this with jquery autocomplete. I also have custom fields i use to fill the completion with too. (this is what i have currently http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/5466/nbro.png)

Comment: I think for such a level of customization you cannot use datalist. All the best for your search!